# 'pip install vllm' fails

Tags: llvm-gcc, llama

when install vllm in windows, i got an error msg.
cuda11.7, torch2.0.1+cu117.
i suspect it is due to version compatibility and downgraded cuda from 12.2 to 11.7. but still not working.

```
File "C:\Users\rdlul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cuc9tr4u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 88, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\rdlul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cuc9tr4u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\rdlul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cuc9tr4u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 499, in build_extensions
          _check_cuda_version(compiler_name, compiler_version)
        File "C:\Users\rdlul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cuc9tr4u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 383, in _check_cuda_version
          torch_cuda_version = packaging.version.parse(torch.version.cuda)
        File "C:\Users\rdlul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cuc9tr4u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 52, in parse
          return Version(version)
        File "C:\Users\rdlul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cuc9tr4u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 196, in __init__
          match = self._regex.search(version)
      TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for vllm
Failed to build vllm
ERROR: Could not build wheels for vllm, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Windows not supported  https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/669